# JStree event select_node and c#

Tags: c#, events, jstree

I  have a problem with the events of JStree and the **"<%"** tag.

```
$("#jstree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(evt, data)
{
     <% brancheSelectionnee(infosFilles[niveau][ligne][0]); %>
     alert(data.node.text);
});
```

The **"alert"** show me  the name of my node, everytime this node is selected but the function between **<% %>** is in my C#, and is called immediatly, even if my node is not clicked :

I want this function to be called just as the **"alert"**, only when I click on the node.

nb : The alert is in a loop, stuck until I choose another node. It's not a problem, but  I don't know if it is the normal behaviour

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I made a tree, and when the user will click on the last branch, he will trigger a C# function.

The last Idea is : Click on the branch -> Go searching on the SQL server a document -> Display this document

Comment: the same can be achieved by making an ajax request to a api controller.And you can avoid direct server side call.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer : I'll try something, but I never used any technique like that

Comment: you need some heads up?

Comment: I'll use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508409/ajax-method-call as an exemple, I already succeed to go in the "sayHello" function, I just have to go from this function to my C# code

Thanks !