# call to string controller function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following method

```
    public string TyneMice()
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\...\myhtml.html");
    }
```

I want to call above string method (TyneMIce) using jQuery . whats the syntax  need to use ?

Comment: You mean `ajax` call??

Comment: nope without ajax , I just want to call this function

Comment: That function isn't javascript/jquery.  If it's a server-side function you have to do a httprequest of some kind.  AJAX is a way to do such a request with javascript.

Comment: @James yes this function is in c# , I want to call this when View Page loading. so all you saying is I cannot use jquery to call this ?

Comment: @kez no you can't use client-side languages with server-side languages. the only way this can be achieved is using Ajax to request data from the server. See this detailed answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/171210

Comment: @Joseph118 I tried like this as you guys said , but seems like method not invoking 1. https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yq4GA/ajax-call 
2. https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/KK7x7/ajax-to-call-string-method

Comment: @kez you are almost there. Now take a look at this answer to help you call your method http://stackoverflow.com/a/4508430