# ajax call for string method not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to set a html content to TinyMCE editor content in ASP.NET MVC

so I come come with a solution that convert that HTML file to string in server side and then call it using ajax in client side

this is C# controller method

```
[HttpGet]
public string TyneMice()
{
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\..\myhtml.html");
}
```

this is ajax call ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

          tinymce.init({

            ...,

            setup: function (ed) {
                ed.on("init", function (ed) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "Brochure/TyneMice",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {

                            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);
                        },

                        error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
                    });

                })
            }

        });

 </script>
```

But Once I put debug point on above string method it is not invoking

Then I put above script inside `$( document ).ready(function() { ... }`

But the same result it doesnt work.

Comment: try replacing dataType with false and we rather than using replace string with IActionResult in vnext and ActionResult in other version and return Content

Comment: What errors are you getting? Your url should be `url: @Url.Action("TyneMice", "Brochure")',` and your returning a `string`, not json so either use `return Json(...)` or use `dataType: "text",`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've changed as you said but no errors occurring while compile time or run time , still that debug point not invoking

Comment: @blin2linkme you meant like this  `dataType: false,` and   `public string IActionResult()
        {`

Comment: `tinymce.init({` then `ed.on("init", function (ed) {` does not look right. Try commenting out the line `ed.on("init", function (ed) {` and its closing `});`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried like this as you mentioned `tinymce.init({
            ....,setup: function (data) {$.ajax({ type: "GET",                 url:'@Url.Action("TyneMice", "Brochure")',contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function (data) {

                            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);
                        },

                        error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
                    });  }

        });` but seems like then tinymce editor missing once I do that

Comment: Looking at the docs, `setup` is only for attaching events. I think what you want is [setContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent) (but I'm not familiar with TinyMCE so not sure)

Comment: if above Ajax call success I've sets the HTML contents of the activeEditor editor
`tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);` so Im in right path noh ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93569/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Comment: @StephenMuecke once I use in this way `var content;     $.ajax({type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("TyneMice", "Brochure")',
            .....,
            success: function (data) {
                content = data;
            },
            error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
        }),
 
        tinymce.init({ .............,
            setup: function (ed) {
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content, { format: 'html' });       
            } });` this is how it look like , TinyMCE editor not loading http://s22.postimg.org/68exg1rjl/erer.jpg

Comment: @StephenMuecke is this TyneMice() method should be inside the viewpage or codebehind one( .cshtml file or .aspx file)? like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508409/ajax-method-call/4508430#4508430

Comment: Not sure what your saying. There is no 'code behind' in MVC (and MVC can have either `.cshtml` (razor) of `.aspx` files.

Comment: @StephenMuecke in this question answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508409/ajax-method-call/4508430#4508430 he put that string method code inside .aspx page , shall I follow like that , is it good approch

Comment: That only because its a very old answer (before razor) It makes no difference. Stick with your `.cshtml` files

Comment: @StephenMuecke can I add string method code inside .cshtml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Action should return of type ActionResult. The action will return Json object with JsonRequestBehavior set as AllowGet.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult TyneMice()
{           
    return Json("TyneMice Example", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: where should I refer the html file or its content in your approach ?

Comment: The code line will be  `return Json(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\..\myhtml.html"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`