# Page should not refresh when I click on a checkbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My page is refreshing every time I click on a check-box. I am using JavaScript as follows:

```
input.setOnkeypress("if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('search_report_form:search_button').onclick(); return true}");

final class GroupsSelector extends BaseRenderablePanel<GroupsSelector> {
        private GroupsSelector group(LabourInputReportCriteria.Level level) {
            HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox box = new HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox();
            boolean isSelected = selections.isGroupSelected(level);
            box.setSelected(isSelected);
            // box.setDisabled(isDaySelectedOnFirst(level));
            box.setId("groupBy" + level.getClass().getSimpleName());
            box.setOnclick("submit()");
            box.addValueChangeListener(u.addExpressionValueChangeListener("#{reportSearchCriteriaModel.groupBy}"));
            HtmlOutputText labelComponent = new HtmlOutputText();

            labelComponent.setValue(getGroupSelectionValue(level));
            tr().td();
            html(box);
            html("&nbsp;");
            html(labelComponent);
            endTd().endTr();
            return this;
        }
```

Is there any way to avoid refreshing of my page each-time I click on a check box?

Please help.

Thanks,
Shruthi

Comment: remove  box.setOnclick("submit()");

Comment: it will submit everytime you click on checkbox

Comment: But the chechbox count is not generated when I  remove box.setOnclick("submit()"); . In the webpage it shows checkbox count too whenever I select a checkbox.

Comment: what is chechbox count ?

Comment: i don't know your logic i just see your problem and according to that i found what may generate problem that's all

Comment: When i select 1st check box, It will show a 1 in the braces next to value, when I select second checkbox, it will show 2 i the braces next to the valueand so on. So, if I remove remove box.setOnclick("submit()"); , the count is not shown up.

Comment: it means on every click it submit the form so it's obvious that page get rendered and referesh

Comment: i suggest to use jquery if possible, it will not referesh the whole page

Comment: Is there any other way to avoid reloading other than removing remove box.setOnclick("submit()");  line ?

Comment: use Jquery or Ajax Call

Comment: Actually I am not so familiar with the jquery. How am I supposed to do the above code in jquery?

Comment: as hint: first chagne box.setOnclick("submit()"); to box.setOnclick("<ANY JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION>"); so it will call that javascript function and in that function call ajax to your page :: for reference of ajax call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508409/ajax-method-call and on success method add your logic

Comment: Okay. I will try it. Thank you so much.

Comment: enjoy....happy coding