# Internal server error when jquery call c# function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, web

I am trying to make c# function call from jquery by using following codes. But I only get Internal server error. Please help me to find out why and how I have to fix it. Thank you.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".matrix_tableActive").click(function (e) {
            alert(e.target.id);
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Download",
                data: JSON.stringify({ sth: "hahaha" }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: fnsuccesscallback,
                error: fnerrorcallback
            });
        });




    function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
        alert(data.d);

    }
    function fnerrorcallback(result) {
        alert(result.statusText);
    }

    });
</script>
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
    protected static String Download(String sth)
    {
       return sth;
    }
```

Comment: found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508409/ajax-method-call

Comment: Please find out exact error and update post. At this point post asking for general debugging help which is a too broad for SO.

Comment: Thanks @wit_peter I found the correct way from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

try calling it like,

```
window.PageMethods.Download('hahaha',fnsuccesscallback,fnerrorcallback)
```

This is same as calling AJAX method. except for parameters, OnSuccess and OnError functions, everything else is taken care of internally.

Also according to me web method must be `public` and `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be `public` as you are calling it from javascript.
It should be like

```
[WebMethod]
public static String Download(String sth)
{
   return sth;
}
```

Also to know the error detail you should use the `error` as below

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}
```