# How can I call c# method from Jquery Ajax in WebForm?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am new to the coding and i am trying to call my c# method through jquery ajax because my form action is not allowing my OnClick() event to run, I cannot remove form action because,  my form comes from proprietary software and gives form action automatically every time, i tried to change it to default again but that doesn't work. So now I am trying to run my C# code through Jquery Ajax. If you have better way to solve it please suggest.
Your help is appreciated, Thank You in advance

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HTMLtoPDF.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="HTMLtoPDF.HTMLtoPDF" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<title>Incomplete Grade Application</title>

</head>
<body>
   <form action="xyz.aspx" id="form1" runat="server"  method="post" name="form1">


  /// Web Form ///



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label class="control-label" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:20px">Please use your mouse/finger sign below:</label>
                <div id="esignature"></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="bitmap" name="bitmap" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="clear">Clear Signature</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-6 col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-6">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="reject-button" name="button" value="Reject" />

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

                <input type="button" ID="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Approve" />

               <button id="hiddenButton" runat="server" onserverclick="btnClick_Click" style="display:none;" ></button>

            </div>

        </div>

        <hr style="background-color:#750D17;height:1px" />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <input type="text1" class="form-control" id="reject-reason" name="reject-reason">

                <p class="help-block">Reject Reasons (if rejected)</p>
            </div>


        </div>





    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />

</form>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://workflow.stratford.edu/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src='https://workflow.stratford.edu/Content/jSignature/flashcanvas.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src='https://workflow.stratford.edu/Content/jSignature/jSignature.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var isEmpty = function (element) {
        if ($("#" + element).val() == "" || $("#" + element).val() == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    };

    var arrayCheck = function (array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == false) {
                return false;
            }

        };

        return true;
    };

    function arrayAssign(array, num) {
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            array[i] = false;

        };

        return array;
    };



    function validationCheck(array, number, element) {
        if (isEmpty(element)) {
            $("#" + element).parent(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            array[number] = false;
        } else {
            $("#" + element).parent(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            array[number] = true;
        }
    };

    var pass1 = [];





    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            if (parseInt($.browser.version) < "9.0") {
                alert("Sorry! This form does not support your current IE version, please use Firefox/Google Chrome to submit.");
            }
        }

        var preSig = $('#stu-sig-bit').val();
        $('#stu-sig').attr('src', preSig);
        var fakeVari = $("#typea").val();

        $("#esignature").jSignature({
            "background-color": "transparent",
            "decor-color": "transparent",
            "color": "#1489FF",
        });

        $("#clear").click(function () {
            $("#esignature").jSignature("reset");
        });



        $("input[type=text]").attr("readonly", true);
        $("textarea1").attr("readonly", true);
        //$("input[type=radio]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#reject-reason").attr("readonly", false);




        $("#submit").click(function () {


            $("#bitmap").val($("#esignature").jSignature("getData"));

            arrayAssign(pass1, 2);
            pass1[2] = false;

            validationCheck(pass1, 0, "remaining_work");
            validationCheck(pass1, 1, "deadline_date");


            pass1[2] = true;

            if (!arrayCheck(pass1)) {
                return false;
            }
            else if ($("#esignature").jSignature("getData", "native").length == 0) {
                alert("Please sign at bottom of the form.");
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#iso_sig").val($("#bitmap").val());
                $("#iso_decision").val("no");
                var date = new Date();
                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                var day = date.getDate();
                var temp = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month + "/" + (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                $("#iso_date").val(temp);

                var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to approve the case?');
                if (answer == true) {

                    document.getElementById('<%= hiddenButton.ClientID %>').click();


                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }



        });


        $("#reject-button").click(function () {


            $("#bitmap").val($("#esignature").jSignature("getData"));
            if (isEmpty("reject-reason")) {
                alert("Please write down the reason why you reject the request.");
                return false;
            } else if ($("#esignature").jSignature("getData", "native").length == 0) {
                alert("Please sign at bottom of the form.");
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#iso_sig").val($("#bitmap").val());
                $("#iso_decision").val("no");
                var date = new Date();
                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                var day = date.getDate();
                var temp = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month + "/" + (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day + "/" + date.getFullYear();
                $("#iso_date").val(temp);

                var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to reject the case?');
                if (answer == true) {

                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }



        });



    });
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DownloadAsPDF();
    }

    public void DownloadAsPDF()
    {
        try
        {
            string strHtml = string.Empty;
            string pdfFileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\files\\" + "CASEID6.pdf";
            //string testPath = Server.MapPath("~/files/test.pdf");

            string template = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Incomplete-Pdf-temp.html"));


            CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(template, pdfFileName);

            Response.Redirect("SendEmail.aspx");




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }



    public void CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(string HtmlStream, string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            object TargetFile = FileName;

            string ModifiedFileName = string.Empty;
            string FinalFileName = string.Empty;




            GeneratePDF.HtmlToPdfBuilder builder = new GeneratePDF.HtmlToPdfBuilder(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
            GeneratePDF.HtmlPdfPage first = builder.AddPage();
            first.AppendHtml(HtmlStream);
            byte[] file = builder.RenderPdf();
            File.WriteAllBytes(TargetFile.ToString(), file);

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(TargetFile.ToString());
            ModifiedFileName = TargetFile.ToString();
            ModifiedFileName = ModifiedFileName.Insert(ModifiedFileName.Length - 4, "1");

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, new FileStream(ModifiedFileName, FileMode.Append), iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS, "", "", iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);
            reader.Close();
            if (File.Exists(TargetFile.ToString()))
                File.Delete(TargetFile.ToString());
            FinalFileName = ModifiedFileName.Remove(ModifiedFileName.Length - 5, 1);
            File.Copy(ModifiedFileName, FinalFileName);
            if (File.Exists(ModifiedFileName))
                File.Delete(ModifiedFileName);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508409/ajax-method-call)

Comment: @Dhaval will it work because the method in C# file is void and it need static, cause i tried the example given in that link but it only gives alert message of success but doesn't call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You would implement a web-service, or you would utilize a handler file.  This generic handler is often used, since it doesn't require a form.  Once you utilize the template you'll have a file that should appear as follows:

```
public class SampleHandler : IHttpHandler
{
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {

     }

     public bool IsReusable
     {
          get { return false; }
     }
}
```

From your primary application, or form, you would execute your ajax as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
         url: '<% Page.ResolveUrl("/SampleHandler.ashx") %>',
         method: 'post', 
         ...,
         success : function (response) {
              // Handle .ashx response.
         }
     });
</script>
```

That is one of the simplest approaches.  As it will allow you to separate your logic, compared to the declaration of a method in your code behind decorated in a `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Comment: I created handler as you told, but i don't know where can shall i put my c# code ?

Comment: @Naive Your C# code would go inside the process request, and you would return it via the current `HttpContext` and you can access particular data through the `HttpContext`.

Comment: Can i directly call C# code with jquery ajax ?
     
       $.ajax({
         url: '<% Url("page1.aspx/HTMLtoPDF") %>',
         method: 'post', 
         success : function (response) {
              alert("success");
         }
         });

Comment: @Naive Well, you could hit that .aspx page, then have the page load return content by `HttpContext.Response.End();` but that really isn't the correct way.  You really should abstract outward, and use a service to handle that functionality for you automatically.

Comment: thank you, right now i am trying to implement through handler as you said, will let you know what the output is, but i really appreciate your help.

Comment: I did as you said, i just kept alert box in success, it gives me alert message but doesn't run the code in background which is to convert pdf and redirect the page by sending email.

Comment: I'm preoccupied at the moment, it does work.  I've done it on several sites.  I'll see if I can help you later when I have more time.