# Getting data from a .cs file to a .cshtml

Tags: javascript, html, razor-pages

I'm trying to pass the data received from my function to a .cshtml file that uses javascript.

```
public static int LastID()
        {
            int LastArticleNr;
            SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection(null);

            conn.Open();
            LastArticleNr = conn.QueryFirstOrDefault <int> ("SELECT CAST(isnull(last_value,0) AS INT) AS ID FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Artikel')");
            conn.Close();

            return LastArticleNr;
        }
```

Now I don't know whether this is possible or not, or whether I would need to use a different method of getting this data. However what I've tried is simply calling the function which, to probably no-ones surprise didn't do much. I've also tried this:

```
@using namespace.Classes.DataLayer;
@{
var LastID = DataLayer.LastID();
}
```

However even if the using clause *should* include the class in which this function exists, it fails to recognise the DataLayer class.

Comment: That should be `@using Classes.DataLayer`.

Comment: @Mike That only brings up that it is "unnecessary" yet it is unable to recognise the ```var LastID = DataLayer.LastID();```

Comment: Need some more detail about where the LastID method is in relation to the calling page.

Comment: It is within namespace.Classes.DataLayer under a file called DataLayer.cs which is what I'm calling here and it just won't recognise it. I don't understand AJAX like at all and don't get why this just keeps saying the function LastID doesn't exist.

Comment: So you have a namespace called "namespace"? Why?

Comment: @Mike Well no I don't but it's essentially just the name of the project file that I'm rewriting as namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how your application is structured. Like: What error do you get when you try to access the Data Access Layer?
But If this is being done on page load, you could pass the data into TempData:

```
TempData['LastId'] = LastID();
```

And then in your razor page:

```
@{
    var lastId = TempData['LastId'];
  }
```

However if you wanted to get it at any time after the page has loaded and do not want to refresh the page, you would have [make an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4508430/15147229)

Comment: I only need to get it on page load and frankly, I don't understand ajax one bit. But it doesn't recognise LastID() within TempData.

Comment: Can I see how you set it? Share a code snippet please.

Comment: fixed it by calling it as @TempData['LastId'] in the function for some reason it works there but not at the top of the file within @{ works now!

Comment: Yeah, you can use razor in any part of a .cshtml file(even in JavaScript although it's advisable), as long as you have @{}. I'm happy you're able to figure it out.